# Sheets JavaScript API Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

I'm playing around with the new version of the Google Sheets API in my Aurelia application (I'm using TypeScript). I've managed to login the user and ask for the required scopes but when I'm trying to get the values of a spreadsheet the API throws the following error:

> cb=gapi.loaded_0:269 Uncaught Error: arrayForEach was called with a non array value(…)

This is how I initialize the API and login the user:

```
gapi.load("auth2", () => {
    gapi.auth2.init({
       'client_id': this.clientId,
       'scope': this.scopes.join(' ')
    }).then(() => {
           this.auth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
           this.auth.signIn().then(response => {
               gapi.load("client", () => {
                     gapi.client.load("sheets", "v4", () => {
                         gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                             spreadsheetId: this.testSheet,
                             range: 'Class Data!A2:E'
                          }).then((response) => {console.log(response);});
                     });
               });
           })
    });
});
```

The `scopes` variable is an array of scopes:

```
scopes: string[] = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
```

The user logs in successfully, I can even get their name and email. After loading the Sheets API I've checked `gapi.client' and the 'sheets' object is there but when I try to get data from a spreadsheet it fails with the above error. The example I'm running is against Google's public spreadsheet that is used in [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js) example. Also note that there is nothing wrong with my client id as I've run Google's sample code with it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Sheet named *Class Data*?, if so, it might be necessary to specify the range as follows:

```
range: "'Class Data'!A2:E"
```

This is certainly true within the Sheets UI and Apps Scripts, and I'm trying to remember if I experienced the same with the JS client library.

Comment: Tried it.. It didn't work. I've copied the value for `range` directly from Google's example but it still does not seem to be working...

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the sample now and the sample does appeat to work fine, so that's not the issue... Two questions on your scopes: you're requesting both readonly and full access for Drive and Sheets, surely you need only request one or other (readonly or not) depending on whether you're wanting to grant write access? Secondly, is the Drive API enabled?

Comment: The Drive API was not enabled, only the Sheets API was. I enabled it now but the error persists. I've tried running the code just with the readonly scope. I included all available scopes just to be sure the error had nothing to do with them

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use gapi and ended up having the same error bringing me to this issue.

Because I am using Visual Studio 2019 with "Web Live Preview" enabled it overrides several prototype methods and one of them is Array.prototype.forEach.

I disabled "Web Live Preview" in "Tools>Options>Web live preview" and it worked.

[Tools>Options>Web live preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG8Uq.png)

I know this case is Visual Studio specific, but the override issue may give some guidance to those who have this problem.