# Loading Aurelia breaks Google API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-js-client, aurelia

I have created a reproduction of this bug here (ugly use of Aurelia but to prove the point): https://jberggren.github.io/GoogleAureliaBugReproduce/

If I load Google API and try to list my files in Google Drive my code derived from [Googles quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) works fine. If I use the same code after loading Aurelia I get a script error from gapi stating

`Uncaught Error: arrayForEach was called with a non array value
    at Object._.Sa (cb=gapi.loaded_0:382)
    at Object._.eb (cb=gapi.loaded_0:402)
    at MF (cb=gapi.loaded_0:723)
    at Object.HF (cb=gapi.loaded_0:722)
    at Object.list (cb=gapi.loaded_0:40)
    at listFiles (index.js:86)
    ...`

When debugging it seems to be some sort of array check (Chroms says 'native code') that failes after Aurelia is loaded. In my search for an answer I found two other people with the same problem but no solution ([Aurelia gitter question](https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss?at=58848a47cbcb2817709f55ed), [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704962/sheets-javascript-api-uncaught-error)). Don't know if to report this to the Aurelia team, Google or where the actual problem lays.

Help me SO, you are my only hope.

Comment: you might want to change the scopes of your demo snippet. Not sure there are too many SO contributors that would be happy to give you access to their Drive accounts. Try "drive.file" which restricts access to files created by your app. If this is holding you up, just bypass gapi and craft your own http rest/json requests or use http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/1. You can use gapi for the OAuth bit and then inject the access token into your requests, eg with httpClient.configure

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment. I had thought about the scope, hence the original drive.metadata.readonly but I changed it now to drive.file. This is a repo my actual projects is using another library for simpler file handling that uses gapi underneath. I find the Google api hard to use when getting/saving file content from the client. I just want to save some json (well, and going forward maybe some images).

Comment: imho, using gapi is not a great idea until it's open sourced. I suspect that one or other of gapi/aurelia/a polyfill is overloading a prototype. The Google Drive REST API isn't that hard to wrangle, and if you do it yourself you will get much better control over resumable uploads, partial downloads, throttling, etc etc.

Comment: I had a quick look at your code. Although unrelated to your current problem, iterating the response to files.list until the returned array is empty is NOT the correct way to pull all files. You should iterate until nextPageToken is null/undefined. This is because Drive can return a page of any length from zero to maxPageSize at any time.

Comment: Yeah, as I stated the google api code is based on their quickstart only to give this easy repro so not something I will actually use.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a perfect solution but works.

## aurelia-binding

https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/master/src/array-observation.js

Aurelia overrides `Array.prototype.*` for some reasons.

## gapi (especially spreadsheets)

Gapi lib checks to make sure that is it native code or not.

```
// example
const r = /\[native code\]/
r.test(Array.prototype.push)
```

## conclusion

So, we have to monkey patching.

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', async () => {
  await gapi.client.init({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    discoveryDocs: ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
  });
  // monkey patch
  const originTest = RegExp.prototype.test;
  RegExp.prototype.test = function test(v) {
    if (typeof v === 'function' && v.toString().includes('__array_observer__.addChangeRecord')) {
      return true;
    }
    return originTest.apply(this, arguments);
  };
});
```

Comment: This answer is a bit over my head, but hey, it seems to work!  THANK YOU!!!